# Validate date and compare dates

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using asp.net 4.0. I have created a web user control for date validation. The date format which I am using is `dd-MMM-yyyy`. This control has two textboxes and next to each textbox there is calender extender(Ajax control) and also I am using watermark extender for textboxes. So I want create control such that user either can not enter anything in textbox (Enabled="False") or if user enters date it should validate the date and if the dates are valid I have to compare dates.

When I am disabling textboxes to prevent user to enter text, I am getting textbox value as "null" in control. When I am allowing users to enter text I have to validate date. This problem I have solved some extent by using regular expression. But the main problem I am facing is comparing the two dates. I have used compare validator and I have used tried Jquery for this.  When I am using compare validator, its comparing only days in date not whole date. And when I am using jquery, it is behaving different for diiferent browsers.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem either with compare validator or Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

[Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) and [mement.js](http://momentjs.com/) will help you in this. These libraries provides you more flexibility than just comparing values